# How to open second tab of excel file when linked from powerpoint file

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, excel-2013, powerpoint-2013

I have an Excel 2013 document in .xlsx format having 3 separated tabs. When I open the excel file by double-clicking, I see the first tab opening by default, which is supposed.

I am linking the excel file on MS PowerPoint. However, here I want the second tab comes to the screen by default, but the first page comes.

In short, I want to see the first tab of the excel file when I open it by double-clicking, but want to see the second page when I open the excel file via the link in the PowerPoint. I couldn't find a way to manage it. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using code to create the link in PowerPoint?

Comment: @HackSlash no.. In the top ribbon, I am doing Insert -> Add HyperLink and selecting the excel file.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming related questions. This question would get more answers over at our sister site: https://superuser.com/

Comment: @HackSlash you can offer a programming based solution as well to this if possible, with vba.. But I'll ask on superuser.com too.

Comment: In the workbook.open event use the code: Sheets("Sheet2").activate It is a VBA code. If you don't want to use code then you may hide first sheet in the workbook also.

Comment: @ShivangGupta but if I do that, when I open the excel file manually by double-clicking, it also shows the Sheet2, I want to see Sheet1 in this case.

Comment: In that case, instead of using hyperlink in powerpoint, you may provide a button, which will trigger a sub procedure and after opening the file it will activate the second sheet also.

Comment: You can call Worksheet2 in your VBA